# how to import node in XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

Parent XML

```
<order>
     <class/>
     <account>
        <saving/>
     </account>
</order>
```

I want to import node to parent xml

Node:

```
 <data>
     <address/>
 </data>
```

After importing, final xml as

```
<order>
     <class/>
     <account>
        <saving/>
     </account>
     <data>
         <address/>
     </data>
</order>
```

Please help me here

I tried as below:

> ```
>  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
>  doc.LoadXml(childXML.InnerXml);
>  mlNode newNodeDataset = doc.DocumentElement;
>
> XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
> xdoc.LoadXml(parentXML);
> XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;  
>
> xdoc.ImportNode(newNodeDataset, true);
> ```

It donesn't throwing any error but it is not importing the node.
where i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Again, `XmlDocument` seems irrelevant here. Again, you haven't provided *any code* to show what you've got so far. Again, you used quoting (`>`) pointlessly. *Please* take note of comments on previous questions to help you ask better questions in future - and ideally, read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add the element to the existing document root using the `Add` method, it seems:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("order",
        new XElement("class"),
        new XElement("account",
            new XElement("saving")
        )
    )
);

var element = new XElement("data", new XElement("address"));

doc.Root.Add(element);
```

Result (in `doc`):

```
<order>
  <class />
  <account>
    <saving />
  </account>
  <data>
    <address />
  </data>
</order>
```